# Powershell Expressions in Hashtable

Tags: powershell, expression, hashtable

I've been recently getting more into powershell scripting.  I'm figuring stuff out as I go, but I can't work this problem out.

Basically I know this code works:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited |
Select-Object ExternalDirectoryObjectId, DisplayName,PrimarySmtpAddress, Alias, UserPrincipalName, ArchiveStatus, ArchiveDatabase,FirstName, LastName, RecipientTypeDetails, `
@{Name="EmailAddresses";Expression={
    ($_.EmailAddresses | 
    Where-Object {$_ -clike "smtp:*"} | 
    ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "smtp:",""}) -join "," 
}} |
Export-Csv "C:\temp\export.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Problem is that I want to run commands from several modules on all mailboxes, to produce a single CSV, so I'm doing this:

```
$mailboxes = get-mailbox -resultsize unlimited
$export = @()

foreach($mailbox in $mailboxes)
{
    $UPN = $mailbox.MicrosoftOnlineServicesID
    $mailboxstat = Get-MailboxStatistics $UPN
    $MSOL = get-msoluser -UserPrincipalName $UPN        


    $Properties = @{
        "Object ID" = $mailbox.ExchangeGUID
        "Display Name" = $mailbox.DisplayName
        "Alias" = $mailbox.Alias
        "Primary SMTP Address" = $mailbox.PrimarySMTPAddress
        "Mailbox Size" = $mailboxstat.TotalItemSize
        "First" = $MSOL.FirstName
        "Last" = $MSOL.LastName
        "RecipientTypeDetails" = $mailbox.RecipientTypeDetails
        "ArchiveStatus" = $mailbox.ArchiveStatus
        "ArchiveGUID" = $mailbox.ArchiveGUID
        "LitigationHold" = $mailbox.LitigationHold
        "Licenses"=$MSOL.Licenses
        "ProxyAddresses"= @{Name="EmailAddresses";Expression={($_.EmailAddresses | Where-Object {$_ -clike "smtp:*"}
    }
    write-host $UPN

    #$properties += $x500

    $export += New-Object psobject -property $properties 
    
}
write-host $export
$exportpath = saveAs
$export | 
    select-object "Object ID", "Display Name","Primary SMTP Address","ProxyAddresses","ArchiveStatus","ArchiveGUID",First,Last,LitigationHold, "Mailbox Size" | 
    Export-Csv -notypeinformation -path $exportpath
```

Which works apart from the proxy addresses.  If I put the hash/expression code in the Export code, it won't produce the results for each mailbox.  But no matter how else I code it, I can't get it to produce what I want.
I've tried creating a new object within the $properties hashtable, convert-string, pretty much eveyrthing I can think of or find on google.
Can someone assist on how I need to format this code for it to work how I need?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `$exportpath = saveAs` a typo; in your code have you tried `$exportpath = 'C:\temp\export.csv'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is you're defining a hashtable that you're treating like the `Properties` argument for `Select-Object`, but you're then sending that to `New-Object`, which works in a very different way / converts a hashtable to a PSObject, rather than selecting existing properties.

```
$export += ([PSCustomObject]@{
    "Object ID" = $mailbox.ExchangeGUID
    "Display Name" = $mailbox.DisplayName
    "Alias" = $mailbox.Alias
    "Primary SMTP Address" = $mailbox.PrimarySMTPAddress
    "Mailbox Size" = $mailboxstat.TotalItemSize
    "First" = $MSOL.FirstName
    "Last" = $MSOL.LastName
    "RecipientTypeDetails" = $mailbox.RecipientTypeDetails
    "ArchiveStatus" = $mailbox.ArchiveStatus
    "ArchiveGUID" = $mailbox.ArchiveGUID
    "LitigationHold" = $mailbox.LitigationHold
    "Licenses"=$MSOL.Licenses
    "ProxyAddresses"= ($mailbox.EmailAddresses | Where-Object {$_ -clike "smtp:*"}) -join ','
})
```

i.e. instead of providing the code to convert a the current object in the pipeline to a property called EmailAddresses, then having that result assigned to a property called ProxyAddresses, just calculate and assign the value that you want ProxyAddresses to have directly.

I also used `[PSCustomObject]` before the hashtable to convert the hashtable to a PSCustomObject and assign it directly to your array.  If you prefer though, you could continue to hold the hashtable in a variable (e.g. `$properties` as it was previously called), then pass that as an arument to `New-Object` to be converted to a `PSObject` before being assigned to your array.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll give that a go :) 

With regards to the saveAs thing, it's calling a function that throws up a saveAs box, that actually works but may not have copied the code properly (as it wasn't really important to the problem) but good spot :)

Comment: Ok, so I tried that and got a few errors, but fixing a few rogue brackets it now exports an empty field for that column.


I noticed for some reason my copied code for the second bit was missing the for each on the expression in the first (working example) my apologies!

I believe the $mailbox.emailaddresses brings back it's own hashtable containing i.e. {smtp:name@domain.com, X500:name@domain.com, SIP:name@domain.com}  ideally I want to split smtp, X500, SIp etc into seperate columns in the csv, hence that filter on the first code.

Comment: Updated code (apologies, it's weird how it won't let me add more than 500 characters) so I'll split it

$mailboxes = get-mailbox -resultsize unlimited
    $export = @()
    
    foreach($mailbox in $mailboxes)
    {
        $UPN = $mailbox.MicrosoftOnlineServicesID
        $mailboxstat = Get-MailboxStatistics $UPN
        $MSOL = get-msoluser -UserPrincipalName $UPN

Comment: $export +=([PSCustomObject] @{
         
            
            "ProxyAddresses" = ($_.EmailAddresses | Where-Object {$_ -clike "smtp:*"} | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "smtp:",""}) -join ","  
            

        })
        
    }
   
    $exportpath = saveAs
    $export | select-object "Object ID", "Display Name","Primary SMTP Address","ProxyAddresses","ArchiveStatus","ArchiveGUID",First,Last,LitigationHold, "Mailbox Size" | Export-Csv -notypeinformation -path $exportpath

Comment: Ah nice one; glad it helped a bit...  NB: With your code in the above comment you've got `$_.EmailAddresses`; but in this context I don't think you have a `$_` variable (i.e. that represents the current object in the pipeline); but you do have `$mailbox` from your foreach loop, so I'd suggest using that instead.

Comment: Also note if you're doing `-clike 'smtp:*'` then you're doing a case sensitive comparison, so won't get the primary email address; as that has `SMTP` in caps.  You can do `-like` if you don't want it to be case sensitive; but your call based on your requirements.